# leg move in pose mode moves other leg

Tags: rigging, bones

in my blender i created a character and his armature with bones assigning with automathic weights to the body, dont ask me hard questions cause im newbie, i got some problems with my character first i tryed to assign evertying to 1 object so i can move the entire object in animation, not working cause i did part of my character without scalling, so when i move all the body the other part stays there, second when i try to move a leg the other leg moves to and it becomes kinda buggy, i already tryed to create the bones again and again but nothing works, and i need to end this really fast if i can get some help i put the file in upload and send the link here

[image]  Here is the blend file that i uploaded in the website

Comment: A file and screenshots always do help! You can upload 2 screenshots and comment to link to a file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to weightpaint your model. in pose mode you need to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and right click your model. after that go to weight paint mode. then click a specific bone and paint on the mesh its influence. red means this face is affected 100% by the bone. blue means zero. if this is too complex, you should watch one of the many tutorials on youtube :)